# Progid not getting registered in the registry when the C++ class is built in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, com, progid

I created a new C++ class and added the interface and class information in the idl file.
The project is built successfully in VS2013.
However, when I search in the registry for the ClassId/ProgID, it does not find it.

Could anyone please tell what am I missing here.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clarify the issue, particularly with specifying: a) how you search in the registry - by your program or with some tools like regedit? b) refer to manual that you use to register com object to explain what do exactly did (such as http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm or from MSDN)

Comment: I searched in regedit using progID. I also tried searching with classID in regedit.

Comment: Also, I found that tlb file is not getting generated.

Comment: @VishalKhemani See the following post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676149/com-component-registration-during-net-setup-project Perhaps, single not accepted answer will be useful